# Pushing Data into JS Object Not Working Fully

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

While attempting to push another dataset into an already existing array to be displayed on a page, only the first property-data combo will display.

**Create the initial object with testing data, just to check**:

```
    $scope.courseCart = [
  {courseName:'English 1', courseNumber:'123456A', additionalNotes:''},
  {courseName:'Calculus Honors', courseNumber:'MAT111', additionalNotes:'Latest possible time'}];
```

**Function to attempt to add to said dataset**:

```
    $scope.AddCourseToCart = function () {
    $scope.courseCart.push({courseName:$scope.courseTitle, courseNumber:'MAT111'});
};
```

When the data is pushed, it yield only the courseName information and not the courseTitle as well.

---

Information is being shown using an ng-repeat on the courseCart object

```
<div ng-repeat="course in courseCart">
              <b>Course Title:</b> {{ course.courseName }}<br />
              <b>Course Number:</b> {{ course.courseTitle }}<br />
              <b>Additional Notes:</b> {{ course.additionalNotes }}<br />
              ---
          </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

`<b>Course Number:</b> {{ course.courseTitle }}<br />`

when you actually want to have

`<b>Course Number:</b> {{ course.courseNumber}}<br />`

Comment: Ah, yes. I'm dumb and somehow missed that.